# How to put the content of a file in an environment variable in circleci?

Tags: bash, circleci

I would like to use the content of a file in an environment variable in CircleCI.
Is this possible?
So far, I tried this in my circle.yml

```
machine:
  environment:
    AMI_DESCRIPTION: "$(cat DESCRIPTION.TXT)"

dependencies:
  override:
    - echo "DESC $AMI_DESCRIPTION"
```

But when running, it just outputs:

```
echo "DESC $AMI_DESCRIPTION"
DESC
```

I also tried to add

```
deployment:
  production:
    branch: master
    commands:
      - ./packer/packer build -var 'ami_desc="$(cat DESCRIPTION.TXT)"' template.json
```

but 'ami_desc' is still empty.

Answer (score 4):

1) Run this command on your machine.

```
ENV_VAR="$(cat filePath | base64)"
```

2) Copy the output of `echo $ENV_VAR` and set it manually on CircleCi

3) While CircleCi running, the file can be retrieve using :

```
echo $ENV_VAR | base64 --decode > filePath
```

Comment: can you add the answer for a case where you don't want to set it manually as an env var in the Project or Organization Settings?